# Probability of game ending with 10 quarters and 5 dimes?

Tags: probability

This is a problem from a practice exam I was given, and I was wondering if you could help me figure it:

> A box has 5 quarters and 3 dimes. You draw a coin from the box and return it to the box with another coin of the same type. That is, if you draw a quarter, you put it back in the box with another quarter. If you draw a dime, you put it back in the box with another dime. When you perform this procedure a total of 7 times, what is the probability that the box has 10 quarters and 5 dimes?

I came up with a solution using a series of series. The problem is that the answer would take too long on an exam, and this is a practice exam. Anyone have a relatively short way of solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our $7$ trials, we need to make a net gain of $2$ dimes and $5$ quarters. There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select the trials in which we gained a dime.  So there are $\binom{7}{2}$ paths along which we could end up with $5$ dimes and $10$ quarters.

Imagine tracing out **one** particular path among these $\binom{7}{2}$ paths, and computing its probability.

The *denominators* in the probability calculation will be $8$, then $9$, and so on up to $14$. For our first choice is made from $8$ coins, and our last choice is made from $14$.

The *numerators* will be once $3$, once $4$ (for winning the dimes) and once $5$, once $6$, once $7$, once $8$, and once $9$ (for winning the quarters).

Thus the required probability is
$$\binom{7}{2}\frac{\left[(3)(4)\right]\left[(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)\right]}{(8)(9)(10)(11)(12)(13)(14)}.$$